# Connecting gremlin CLI to a remote tinkerpop gremlin-server

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

Using `gremlin-javascript`, I'm connecting to a remote server using:

```
const gremlin = require('gremlin')
const Graph = gremlin.structure.Graph
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection
const graph = new Graph()

const g = graph
  .traversal()
  .withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin'))
```

From the gremlin CLI, I can setup a `TinkerGraph` using

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
```

However, I'd like to connect to my Graph at `localhost:8182`.  This doesnt't quite do the trick:

```
gremlin> graph = RemoteGraph.open('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin')
```

And this isn't quite it either:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
gremlin> g = graph.traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin'))
```

How would I connect to this server from the CLI?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gremlin Console has built in support for this and it is described in detail [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-via-console). The basic connection command is:

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
==>Configured localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
```

at which point you can issue traversals against the remote graph:

```
gremlin> :> g.V().values('name')
==>marko
==>vadas
==>lop
==>josh
==>ripple
==>peter
```

If you'd like to drop the `:>` syntax you can put the REPL in "console" mode and that prefix will no longer be necessary:

```
gremlin> :remote console
==>All scripts will now be sent to Gremlin Server - [localhost/127.0.0.1:8182]-[5ff68eac-5af9-4140-b3b8-d9311f30c053] - type ':remote console' to return to local mode
```

Comment: Aha, I got as far as the remote connection, but my commands which referenced g were being bounced back.  I needed to enter `console mode`  Thanks again!